# Delete Minimize Button

Tags: 12.04, unity, customization

Is there a way to get rid of the minimize button when the window is maximized? I've already gone into gconf-editor /apps/metacity/general/button_layout and changed "close,minimize,maximize" to "close,maximize" but that doesn't affect the buttons when windows are maximized.

Comment: I believe that when maximised, the Window buttons are being drawn by Compiz, not Metacity.

Comment: That could be, but I couldn't find it there either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; Unity [does not](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/740232/comments/30) support customizing the layout of the buttons in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ubuntu 12.04, go to the `dconf-editor`.

Navigate to org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> preferences and in the right-hand-side panel select button-layout, remove minimize and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then your minimize button must be disappeared. Is that what you mean?